# How can I target < and > with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with an badly designed system that I'm trying to import orders from Opencart to. The problem lies in that it does not accept float values as float, ie. with a dot, but requires a comma, which means that `<RowUnitPrice>6.4516</RowUnitPrice>` must be converted to `<RowUnitPrice>6,4516</RowUnitPrice>`. This I have managed to do with the following regex:

`/(?<=\d)\.(?=d)/`

This created a problem, however. There was a product that had a product code, which matched and got replaced. Thus `<RowArticleCode>CLA713/1.5</RowArticleCode>` became `<RowArticleCode>CLA713/1,5</RowArticleCode>`. I modified my regex to the following:

`/(?<=[>\d])\.(?=[\d<])/`

The intention is to only match for example `>000.000<`, but the problematic article code still gets matched and replaced and I don't know why. What am I not getting here?

Comment: The `.` in `1.5` is surrounded by digits, which your regex allows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
/(?<=\>)(\d+)\.(\d+)(?=\<)/g
```

And you can use substitution with captured groups: `$1,$2` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eO6nY3/2)

Comment: Worked beutifully, but only without the `/g`. Final solution: 
`$xmlstr = preg_replace('/(?<=\>)(\d+)\.(\d+)(?=\<)/', '$1,$2', $dom->saveXML());` And thank you for pointing me to regex101.com. I had only used regexr.com and it does not support looahead and lookbehind.